# Find $a$ for which $f(x) = e^{2x}- (a+1)e^x + x $ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find $a$ for which $f(x) = e^{2x}- (a+1)e^x + x $ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$.

My solution. 
For $f(x)$ to be strictly increasing
$$f'(x)=2e^{2x} - (a+1)e^x +1 > 0$$
That is
$$\Delta=(a+1)^2 - 8  < 0$$
and we find $a \in (-\sqrt{8} -1,\sqrt{8} - 1)$.

But the answer is $ a <\sqrt{8} -1 $.

Please tell me where I am lacking.

Comment: Is it $e^2x$ or $e^{2x}$? If the latter, use the braces $\{,\}$ around the exponent. That is, `$e^{2x}$` produces $e^{2x}$.

Comment: Thanks for the info Clayton

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
2e^{2x} - (a+1)e^x +1 > 0 & \iff (a+1) e^x< 2e^{2x}+1 \\ & \iff a<2e^x+e^{-x}-1.
\end{align}

Now, we consider $g(x)=2e^x+e^{-x}-1.$ We have that $$g'(x)=2e^x-e^{-x}=0\iff x=-\ln \sqrt 2,$$ which is a global minimum of $g$. So

$$a<2e^{-\ln\sqrt 2}-e^{\ln \sqrt 2}-1=\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}+\sqrt 2-1=2\sqrt 2-1.$$